# j_security_check not working when <Context path="">

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jaas, openejb, j-security-check

I use `j_security_check` as part of JAAS mechanism on a tomcat/tomEE server.

I currently have a context called "admin", that has the login process as a separate page (login.html), and that login page has a form similar to this: `<form action="j_security_check" method="post">` with the proper inputs sending j_username & j_password properties.

It all works just fine there.

For clarification, My app is accessible at e.g. "www.myapp.com/admin"

Now I've been asked to add another webapp in the root of the domain, "www.myapp.com", so i add this in my `conf/server.xml`:

```
`<Context 
  docBase="ROOT" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>`
```

`ROOT.war` contains the webapp that needs to be in the `www.myapp.com/` domain path.

What I'm trying to do is add the `j_security_check` mechanism to that context as well (it should be done in `AJAX` instead of a `<form>` for UX reasons).

Note that i've managed to have cookies on both contexts, but when I make a `www.myapp.com/j_security_check` call, I always get a `408 Request Timeout` response.

How can I perform a `j_security_check` call from my app's root context path? (without an external login page please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't following the rules of FORM-based authentication: you need to first request a protected resource, then let the container challenge you for username and password. Upon successful authentication, the container will redirect you to the originally-requested resource. This is covered in section 13.6.3 of the [Java Servlet Specification Version 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1457792373_a57e4c4894acd37fe220dd42540a5b5a). If you want to handle drive-by logins, you 'll need to do that yourself. Servlet 3.0 has `login` methods on the `HttpServletRequest` object, you can just submit your AJAX requests to your own servlet instead of to `j_security_check`.

Note that `<Context>` configuration in your `server.xml` is going to cause endless chaos, and will deploy your ROOT web application twice on the same server. Just put `ROOT.war` into Tomcat's `webapps/` directory and let it auto-deploy.